# How to insert using a sequence with Liquibase

Tags: hsqldb, liquibase

I would like to do a liquibase insert with the primary key being auto generated from the sequence defined in the database. The target database is HSQLDB.

It works to do an insert specifying a value for the primary key

```
<insert ...>
   <column name="TAG_ID" valueNumeric="2"/>
```

I found this (admittedly older) [conversation about it](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/sequence-value-while-inserting-the-data-in-table) but the issue is still the same. The suggested fix doesn't work for HSQLDB.

Looking at [the docs](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html) I've tried some things like

```
<column name="TAG_ID"  defaultValueSequenceNext="TAG_ID_SEQ" />

<column name="TAG_ID"  defaultValueSequenceNext="TAG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL" />

<column name="TAG_ID"  valueComputed="TAG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL" />

<column name="TAG_ID"  autoIncrement="true" />
```

but none of those put anything in the key when I do the insert (the insert fails on a null primary key).

How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HSQLDB has a setting to use Oracle syntax. You can set HSQLDB to use oracle syntax like so:

```
<changeSet ...
    <sql dbms="hsqldb" >SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE</sql>
</changeSet>
```

After that, it works to do the insert like this:

```
<insert ...
    <column name="TAG_ID" valueComputed="TAG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL"/>
```

Comment: is something similar available for h2?

Comment: H2 has an Oracle compatibility mode as referenced here (http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) but I haven't tried it out, so YMMV. If you find it works, feel free to post back here!